# python web application behaves differenty at differnet times

Tags: python, web

this code runs a sign up page

it takes and check whether it matches with regular expression

here only error case checked

if error is present it should display errors like invalid username, invalid password,password didn't match,invalid email

```
import webapp2
import escape
import regular
form="""
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign Up</title>
<style type="text/css">
  .label {text-align: right}
  .error {color: red}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Signup</h2>
<form method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">
        Username
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="%(username)s">
      </td>
      <td class="error">
         %(user_error)s
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="label">
        Password
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="password" >
      </td>
      <td class="error">
        %(password_error)s
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="label">
        Verify Password
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="verify" >
      </td>
      <td class="error">
        %(verify_error)s
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="label">
        Email (optional)
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="%(email)s">
      </td>
      <td class="error">
        %(email_error)s

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="submit">
  </form>
 </body>

 </html>
```

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

```
   def write_form(self,username="",email="",user_error="",password_error="",verify_error="",email_error=""):
    self.response.out.write(form % {"username" : username,
                                    "email": email,
                                    "user_error": user_error,
                                    "password_error": password_error,
                                    "verify_error": verify_error,
                                    "email_error": email_error})
def get(self):
    self.write_form()
def post(self):
    username=self.request.get('username')
    password=self.request.get('password')
    verify=self.request.get('verify')
    email=self.request.get('email')

    flag=True
    if not (regular.valid_username(username)):
          user_error="invalid username"
          flag=False
    if not (regular.valid_password(password)):
          password_error="invalid password"
          flag=False
    if not (password==verify):
          verify_error="password didnt match"
          flag=False
    if email and not (regular.valid_email(email)):
          email_error="invalid email"
          flag=False
    if not flag:      
       self.response.out.write(password_error)
       self.response.out.write(user_error)
           self.write_form(username,email,user_error,password_error,verify_error,email_error)
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
 ], debug=True)
```

Comment: can you provide a *minimal* example? It seems that there's so much more that can go wrong in your code, so reducing the problem is essential.

Comment: thanks..man..i found the error

Answer (score 0):

it is because i did not initialise all the errors before calling the method

```
write_form(...   )
do this
     user_error=""
     password_error=""
     verify_error=""
     email_error=""
```

and you will be good to go

Comment: I'd prefer if you'd just deleted your error. The problem is specific to *your* code and will not help anyone else.